# Number of identical substring pairs in a sequence

Tags: combinatorics, summation, asymptotics

Suppose that we have a sequence $S$ of $n$ identical symbols. I want to count all the possible pairs of repeated subsequences of $S$ (overlapping is allowed). So, according to this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521585198) it's $\Theta(n^4)$. I thought of taking sequences of length $1$, then of length $2$ all the way up to length $n-1$ as follows:
$$\sum\limits_{i=2}^n{{i}\choose{2}}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{{i}\choose{2}}={{n+1}\choose{3}}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-2)!3!}=\Theta(n^3)$$
Am I missing any pairs here since it is only $\Theta(n^3)$?

**EDIT**

The text specifically states:

> Before developing algorithms for finding
>   repetitive structures, we must carefully define those structures. A
>   poor definition may lead to an avalanche of output. For example, if a
>   string consists of n copies of the same character, an algorithm
>   searching for all pairs of identical substrings (an initially
>   reasonable definition of a repetitive structure) would output
>   $\Theta(n^4)$ pairs, an undesirable result.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. Another way to look at the problem would be that there are $n \choose 2$ possible pairs of subsequence starting points and at most $n$ possible length, also showing at most $\Theta(n^3)$. Could it be that you are misunderstanding the problem from the book?

Comment: @Ingix OK, now I have cited the excerpt from the book. Can you check his  definition?

Comment: Yeah, that comment is what you described and what I understood. So either we are both missing something, or that is actually an error.